# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet circumvent unable to append system message

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using the follow VBA to append tables with spreadsheet data.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, strTable, StrFile, True
```

When I append unique IDs that are already in the table, I get a system message "unable to append all the data to the table".

I would rather prevent this message from ever occurring. I would rather have my own message that says there is a problem with the import and exit out of the program without adding any of the data.

How can I do this using VBA. Running from Access 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at this another way to have more control. In scenarios like this I have found it much better/smoother to run the process a follows;

```
Import data into a temporary table ->
Run any validation checks you need to at this stage ->
Append values into the table you are aiming for ->
Delete temp table ->
procedure end
```

This way you will be able to avoid the system errors or requiring any system clicks.

To get around the system messages you can on error resume next prior to the statement or on error go to errhandler and put in your own error handling procedure.

HTH
Mark

Comment: How would I approach doing the error handler? Is these a good site that would show me how to do this?